# Equation to solve for x

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following equation in a string

```
y = 18774x + 82795
```

Solving for `x` I would do this:-

```
x = (y-82795) / 18774
```

I know the value of `y`

However the equation changes all the time and is always in a string format

Is it possible to simply throw the original equation at an Evaluate statement and have it solve for x automatically?

I know I can do things like this:-

```
MsgBox Evaluate("5*(8+3)-2*(3*5)")
```

but in my case it would be

```
MsgBox Evaluate("67657657 = 18774x + 82795")
```

where `y = 67657657`

This obviously throws an error.  Is there an easy way I can solve for `x`?

Otherwise I would need to parse the string and work it out more manually

Comment: Is the equation always of the form **Y = A*X + B**

Comment: Yes, always in that form

Comment: Where is the equation coming from? Like if it is from a regression analysis you can the coefficients directly and avoid strings altogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **A1** place the String:

y = 18774x + 82795

In **A2** place the y-value:

```
67657657
```

Then try this macro:

```
Sub Zolver()
    Dim sTr As String, X As Double
    Dim A As Double, B As Double, Y As Double
    sTr = Range("A1").Value
    sTr = Replace(sTr, " ", "")
    sTr = Replace(sTr, "x", "")
    sTr = Replace(sTr, "y=", "")
    sTr = Replace(sTr, "+", ",")
    A = CDbl(Split(sTr, ",")(0))
    B = CDbl(Split(sTr, ",")(1))
    Y = CDbl(Range("A2").Value)
    X = (Y - B) / A
    MsgBox X
End Sub
```

Comment: Chose this as this is what I ended up using

Comment: `Y` should be extracted from cell "A1" as the given expression is of the form `29394 = 6253x+82373` according to original post.

Comment: What if the user enters `y = 27263+29038x`. This will fail. Look at my answer for a more robust solution.

Comment: @ja72  I like you solution and up-voted it.  I think it is a good starting point to create a general "equation solver"..........good work!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Public Function SolveEquation(ByVal eq As String) As Double
    Dim i_eq As Integer, y As Double
    ' eq : "67657657 = 18774x+82795"
    i_eq = InStr(1, eq, "=")
    y = 0#
    If i_eq > 0 Then
        y = Application.Evaluate(Trim(Left(eq, i_eq - 1)))
        'y =67657657
        eq = Trim(Mid(eq, i_eq + 1))
    End If

    Dim eq_1 As String, eq_2 As String
    Dim x_1 As Double, x_2 As Double
    Dim y_1 As Double, y_2 As Double
    x_1 = 0#: x_2 = 1#
    eq_1 = Replace(eq, "x", "*(" & CStr(x_1) & ")")
    y_1 = Application.Evaluate(eq_1)
    eq_2 = Replace(eq, "x", "*(" & CStr(x_2) & ")")
    y_2 = Application.Evaluate(eq_2)
    ' y_1 = 82795, y_2 = 101569

    ' Alternative solution from evaluation points
    ' SolveEquation = x_1 + (x_2-x_1)/(y_2-y_1)*(y-y_1)

    ' y = a*x+b
    Dim a As Double, b As Double
    a = (y_2 - y_1) / (x_2 - x_1)
    b = y_1 - a * x_1
    ' a= 18774, b = 82795

    ' Solution from linear form y = a*x+b
    SolveEquation  = (y - b) / a
    ' 3599.38542665388

End Function
```

Comment: A more robust solution would be to combine `y` into `b` in the same side of the equation and solve for `a*x+b = 0`. This would take care of cases where `x` is present on the left hand side, like `1+100x = 20x+50`. Also better handling of cases where `*` is present or implicit is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Given you are solving a linear equation:

```
Sub Extract()
Dim strFunc As String
Dim X(1 To 2) As Variant
Dim Y(1 To 2) As Variant
Dim C As Variant
X(1) = 0
X(2) = 100
strFunc = "18774x + 82795"
Y(1) = Evaluate(Replace(LCase$(strFunc), "x", X(1)))
Y(2) = Evaluate(Replace(LCase$(strFunc), "x", X(2)))
C = Application.WorksheetFunction.LinEst(Y, X)
MsgBox "K is " & C(1) & vbNewLine & "M is " & C(2)
End Sub
```